# How to re-establish the connection after network failure in JBoss AS 7.x -JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, jboss7.x

My application is using JPA(Hbernate ORM)  to connect to the SQL server 2008 , Which was deployed in JBoss AS 7.x server. If the network goes down and came up again , i am getting the following exception

```
14:59:27,996 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: The connection is closed.
14:59:28,002 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1361)
14:59:28,012 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1289)
14:59:28,020 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:261)
14:59:28,025 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at com.honeywell.domoweb.dataservice.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl.getUsers(UserDaoImpl.java:372)
14:59:28,030 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
14:59:28,034 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
14:59:28,039 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
14:59:28,044 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
14:59:28,047 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
14:59:28,052 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
14:59:28,058 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
14:59:28,064 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
14:59:28,069 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
14:59:28,075 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
14:59:28,080 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at $Proxy66.getUsers(Unknown Source)
14:59:28,083 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at com.honeywell.domoweb.dataservice.dao.impl.TemplateDaoImpl.getTemplate(TemplateDaoImpl.java:44)
14:59:28,089 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)...
```

I googled out this issue and found that this issue needs a change in the connection pool configuration to reconnect again using autoReconnect attribute ,but didn't found any example ,how to embed the autoReconnect with my Connection pool settings.Below is my Connection pool settings in the Standalone.xml file

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
        <datasources>


            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/DataServiceDS" pool-name="dataServicePool" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://ipaddress:1433;databaseName=myDataBase</connection-url>
                <driver>sqlserver</driver>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>true</prefill>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>usename</user-name>
                    <password>password</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>

                <driver name="sqlserver" module="com.microsoft.sqlserver">
                    <xa-datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
    </subsystem>
```

Can you please let me know ,how to re-connect to the database , if Network goes down and reconnected again ?

Answer (score 6):

you could add

```
<check-valid-connection-sql>select 1 </check-valid-connection-sql>
```

to your data source configuration, or any other sql statement you want. 
This sql statement will be executed every time connection is checkout from the connection pool and if statement would fail, i.e. connection is closed you get, it would be destroyed and recreated/reconnected to sql server. That will make sure that your application (hibernate) always gets working sql connection.

Answer (score 3):

Also had hard time finding example for similar problem. For jboss7 added following lines to datasource configuration

```
<datasource>
  ...
  <validation>
    <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1 from dual</check-valid-connection-sql>
    <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
    <background-validation>true</background-validation>
  </validation>
  ...
</datasource>
```

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to fix ?

If you are trying to stop transactions from failing when the "network goes down".  That is just not possible.  You need to look into "XA" and SQL clustering to solve some parts of that problem.  But I don't think you are looking for this.

..

If you want to stop application operations from failing if they are unlucky enough to be the first user of an idle SQL connection the connection pooler in JBoss was keeping.  Then yes there is something you can do.

The problem is:

- Windows by default disconnects active TCP connections when "the network goes down" other platforms don't do this.  For you I'd guess only one part of the network goes down, meaning the SQL server end if affected but not the JBoss end.
- The connection pooler in the JBoss end will keep TCP connections open with idle connections in the pool.  The JBoss end does not know the network goes down, it may loose contact with SQL server for a short time.  When the network comes up the SQL server end reset/lost all the connections.  But the JBoss end still has "half open connections" it still thinks the connections are valid.
- The JBoss end maybe idle for sometime (seconds/minutes/hours) before it needs to do with with SQL.  Then it goes to get an SQL handle and the connection pooler duly returns one from the pool that is idle.  Not knowing the TCP connection is dead.  The application then uses it to find out the TCP connection gets reset in response to some data being send from client to server and server saying 'I don't have that connection open'.  This forces the SQL driver to close the connection and start returning SQLException to operations on the JDBC handle.

So below I talk in general terms about how to help mitigate or resolve the matter, consult your support channels and SQL documentation:

Things to look into:

- Your connection pooler documentation.  I believe JBoss provide their own connection pool implementation.  So while it is true this matter can be resolved at the connection pooler, it is not clear is the connection pooler with your JBoss version and the one you are already using may have the features in place.
- Enable TCP keepalives, these are low level ping/pong performed by TCP protocol and can usually be in some number of seconds.  The default maybe 1 hour which is too long for SQL maybe 5 minutes is better.
- Enable the connection pooler to check/validate the connection is good and valid before giving it to the application.  This might use internal ping/pong check or might do 'SELECT 1'.  This is probably the easiest/quickest solution to fixing the problem completely, however then can be a measurable performance impact with the extra round trip before use.
- Enable the above point only if the connection has been idle for long than some limit (maybe 60 seconds).  This mitigates the performance impact of enabling it to times when SQL is pretty idle.
- See if your SQL driver support a custom TCP data ping/pong mechanism and see if the connection pooler implementation supports using it.
- Use a short maximum idle time.
- Lower the maximum number of idle connections.
- Enable auto-reconnect if the connection is not in a transaction and if this is the first statement that failed (often the only options changes are autocommit=off then 'BEGIN TRANSACTION' this situation is possible for a driver to detect and recover from seamlessly).

Reccomendations maybe to look at c3p0 connection pooler, if you have a choice to picking an outside 3rd party open source pooler to use.  This may not be the case in a JBoss environment.